# How to display alert only once?

Tags: javascript, alert

I've set an alert to notify users that their password will expire within 15 days. The alert shows up three times: after the initial login, after selecting some login info, and when login is confirmed.

**I need the alert to only appear once, either after the initial login or when login is confirmed.**

How do I do this?

My code:

```
function pwdDaysToExpire() {
    const userData = getStoredUserData();
    const { pwdLastSet } = userData;
    const datepwdLastSet = new Date(pwdLastSet).getTime();
    const dateNow = new Date().getTime();
    const diffInDays = Math.ceil((dateNow - datepwdLastSet) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    return diffInDays;
  }

---

<script type="text/javascript">
{pwdDaysToExpire() >= 76 ? alert(`YOUR PASSWORD WILL EXPIRE IN ${90 - pwdDaysToExpire()} DAYS`) : ''}
</script>
```

Please help!! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you include the code for your pwdDaysToExpire()?

Comment: Is this a single or multi page application?

Comment: It's a multi page app

Comment: Why not keep last alert timestamp in session, or with in `getStoredUserData()` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use localStorage (not compatible with older browsers):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var alerted = localStorage.getItem('alerted') || '';
    if (alerted != 'yes') {
     alert("My alert.");
     localStorage.setItem('alerted','yes');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: This is the simplest solution.

Answer (score -1):

Solved the problem:

Joined the alert and pwdDaysToExpire() and inserted this into handleClick(), which is called on the click of a button.

Alert now appears just once :)

Comment: To much for simple task.